# hmisc::latex tables open in external xdvik window instead of being inserted into the pdf output document

Tags: latex, knitr, lyx, xtable

Since our update to R2.15.1, the tables in my lyx documents that result from calls to the latex function (package Hmisc) open in an external xdvik-window instead of being inserted in the pdf-document that I am compiling.
On the contrary, the tables produced with xtable and the graphs produced with ggplot do appear where they belong in the document.

The chunk header for the latex call is

```
<<Specs,tidy=F,results='asis',eval=F>>=
```

and the chunk is then referred to multiple times with e.g.

```
<<AGESpecs,ref.label='Specs',tidy=F,results='asis',echo=F>>=
```

The tables in the xdvik window do look perfect.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It looks I have to guess from experience since the chunk body was not shown here, and my best guess is you need an argument `file=''` in the function `latex()`, i.e.

```
library(Hmisc)
latex(object, file = '')
```

By default, `latex()` writes the object in a tex file, and compiles it to dvi. That is probably why you saw the xdvik window.