# Windows API error 2 compiling latex pdf on Hmisc describe

Tags: api, latex, hmisc, dvi

I'm getting a message from Windows saying a .dvi file is missing and that my latex pdf cannot be compiled - see below. The procedure I'm trying to output as a latex table is very simple

```
library(Hmisc)
latex(describe(wine))
```

MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Data: C:\Users\abo586\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKOur60\file24bc482ff5a.dvi

Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp

Line: 498
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, 64-bit Service Pack 1 (build 7601)
Invokers: .../rstudio/rsession/Rterm
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\abo586\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\abo586\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\abo586\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\abo586\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\abo586\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `file=' '` in latex() function: [hmisc::latex tables open in external xdvik window instead of being inserted into the pdf output document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141999/hmisclatex-tables-open-in-external-xdvik-window-instead-of-being-inserted-into)